# ""fullSetup" is not a known member of a module" error with nothing seems to be causing it

Tags: python, linux, bash, archlinux

I am trying to write a post-installation script using Python and Bash, and I am having trouble with defining functions. Below is the main file of the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import variables


# Main program loop
while True:
    userResponse = str.lower(input('''What would you like to do?
    f: Starts the full post-install setup
    u: Starts configuring users
    p: Starts the packages setup
    s: Starts the systemctl setup
    c: Starts the configs setup
    q: Terminates the program\n'''))


    if userResponse == 'f':
        print('Starting full post-install setup...')
        variables.fullSetup()

    elif userResponse == 'u':
        variables.configureUsers()

    elif userResponse == 'p':
        variables.installEssentialPackages()

    elif userResponse == 's':
        variables.configureSystemctl()

    elif userResponse == 'c':
        variables.configureSystem()

    elif userResponse == 'q':
        print('Terminating program...')
        quit()

    else:
        print('Input not recognized.')
```

And here is the `variables` file:

```
import subprocess


def configureUsers():
    print('Attempting to configure system users...')
    subprocess.run(
            './post_install_scripts/01_users.sh',
            shell = True)

def installEssentialPackages():
    print('Attempting to install essential packages...')
    subprocess.run(
            './post_install_scripts/02_pkgs.sh',
            shell = True)

def configureSystemctl():
    print('Attempting to configure systemctl...')
    subprocess.run(
            './post_install_scripts/03_systemctl.sh',
            shell = True)

def configureSystem():
    print('Attempting to configure system...')
    subprocess.run(
            './post_install_scripts/04_configs.sh',
            shell = True)

def fullSetup():
    print('Attempting to run a full setup...')
    configureUsers()
    installEssentialPackages()
    configureSystemctl()
    configureSystem()
```

On `line #19`, I am getting the following error:

```
"fullSetup" is not a known member of a module
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong right here. All seems good to me. If you would like to see the entire repo on Github, you can [follow this link to see the entire repo and its contents.](https://github.com/LiterallyJohnny/arch_post_install_setup)

Hopefully someone here can help me out.

**Extra Info**

- I am using Arch Linux
- I have the latest Python version
- I am using Neovim as my editor, [and you can find its dotfiles here.](https://github.com/LiterallyJohnny/Dotfiles/tree/main/configs/nvim)

Comment: `"fullSetup" is not a known member of a module` That doesn't look like a Python error.  Where, exactly, is that error coming from?

Comment: @JohnGordon it's coming from Neovim. I'm using the Pyright language server for Neovim.

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to run this? I just cloned your repo and ran:

```
python3 setup.py
```

and I get this:

```
What would you like to do?
    f: Starts the full post-install setup
    u: Starts configuring users
    p: Starts the packages setup
    s: Starts the systemctl setup
    c: Starts the configs setup
    q: Terminates the program
```

This is using Python 3.7.

I should further clarify, are you seeing this error when you run the code, or just from some type checker like mypy?

Comment: I am getting the error in my editor. I am using the Pyright language server in Neovim.

Comment: My suspicion then is the issue is with the static analysis performed by the language server. If you can run the code successfully, then this static analysis is a red herring. Static analysis of Python is often full of false negatives like this. I imagine there is a way to make Pyright figure it out, perhaps an `__init__.py` file or something like that, but I'm not too familiar with Pyright and whatever typechecker it is using under the hood.

Comment: The error seems to have gone away. I didn't do anything, it just disappeared. I guess that's cool?

Comment: You love to see it! Perhaps your editor just had a stale view of the world.